# I'd like to make a software which will be executed with BIOS

Tags: x86, operating-system, bootloader, bios

I have a little brother who spends his time playing online games. It makes my parent worried. So, I'd like to build a blocking software which will be executed right after booting process.

My program will do

1. Print out questions(related to physics, literature and math), and ask him to type a right answer.
2. If he gives right answer, let him proceed to log in his laptop.
3. If he fails system will be shut down automatically.

So, my question is what should I know in order to accomplish my plan. Or any books to recommend me?

At my University, I 'd been taught only Java and C++ until now.
Through this project, I want to push myself to learn more and do actual practical tasks.

Comment: Don't forget to add the `x86` and `bios` tags.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own bootloader, or you could modify an existing open-source bootloader like GRUB that already has code for printing menus.

You might just make a menu where the prompt is a question and the options (instead of being different things to boot) are just GRUB print commands or shutdown, except for the right answer which goes to the next menu.  If your sibling doesn't find the keystrokes to escape from GRUB's menus to its command-line, or doesn't know what to do with it to boot successfully, that could be useful.

To update with (a) new question(s), you can have that done by a program that runs after the OS boots, so you don't have to figure out how to do that with GRUB's command / config language.  (Although that might be possible if you can use the low digit of the current time as an index into something.)

I think GRUB can work as a UEFI bootloader, so you don't have to set your PC's firmware to boot in legacy BIOS mode.  ("compatibility support modules", aka CSM in the BIOS menu.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment again :) I will definitely search things to be done as you recommended. Also, I want to ask you a question if you have time. Do you think it is possible to download Ubuntu os on top of my brother's windows os, and by implementing it to execute my program after booting process??. It came up my head while I was asking one of my professors.

Comment: @HyeJinJang: Yes, but that would take a LOT more disk space, and make each boot slower.  You might want it to boot with `init=/sbin/quiz-question` to run your program on a Linux text console, and on success your program would override the bootloader's next-boot-only choice and reboot, or something like that.  (e.g. set the bootloader's choice, but then the bootloader itself would change its own default before booting whatever other OS.)

Comment: Oh right :/.. I didnt think about the disk space.. he will be pretty upset if his PC gets slower than now. Thank you a lot @Peter Cordes.

Comment: @HyeJinJang: Having less free disk space doesn't make a computer much slower, except when allocating space for new files on a filesystem that's *very* close to full.  Maybe those were separate thoughts and you meant that slower boots just to run this quiz that he doesn't even want would make him hate it for convenience reasons.

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding :). Neither I want him to have slower boots with my small surprise what he didnt ask for. At most, I want him to be only mad at my small surprise, not because of the speed of boot.